# Office Deployment Tool Excluding apps: Error Code 30182-1011

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, deployment, microsoft-office-2016

I wish to install Office 2016 on Windows 10 without certain apps, like Acces and Outlook. I've downloaded the Office Deployment Tool (ODT). I examined the related questions but the error code 30182-1011 persists.

The ODT is on `C:/Users/Desktop/ODT`. I modified the configuration.
My downloaded install file from Schoolspot.nl is in `C:/Office/Office/Setup.x86.nl-nl_ProPlusRetail_25NUMBERCODE_TX_DB_act_1_`

Here is my configuration:

```
<Configuration>

<Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Branch="Current" Version="16.0.7466.1317" SourcePath="C:\Office" >
    <Product ID="ProPlusRetail" >
      <Language ID="nl-nl" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Access" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="InfoPath" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Lync" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Outlook" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Publisher" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="SharePointDesigner" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Visio" />
    </Product>
</Add>

<Logging Level="Standard" Path="C:\Office\Office\log" />

</Configuration>
```

At a command prompt I run: `C:\users\Guus Bok\Desktop\ODT\setup/configure configuration.xml`

As you see, I run logs, but can't find the solutions in them.